# Add shadow to Canvas element (keeping the element transparent)

Tags: javascript, css, html, canvas

I have a circle shape in my HTML5 canvas. I'd like to give it a shadow style but without showing the stroke, so the stroke should be 0 and shadow: visible.

Here is my code:

```
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.shadowColor = 'black';
context.strokeStyle = "rgba(255,0,0,1)";
context.shadowBlur = 10;
context.shadowOffsetX = 0;
context.shadowOffsetY = 0;
context.arc(x, y, 45, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
context.restore();
context.save();
```

I found a similar method online but it does not work and honestly I don't understand it.

```
context.beginPath();
context.lineWidth = 10;
RGraph.setShadow({'context': context}, 'black', 0, 0, 15)
context.arc(mouseXY[0], mouseXY[1], radius + 5, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
```

Any Idea to make to have a shadow for an invisible shape ?

Comment: Not sure If it's what you are looking for but what about box-shadow css?

Comment: @KyleT I am not sure I can have box-shadow for a shape in canvas. :/

Comment: @KyleT what lead you to a conclusion that `box-shadow` (a CSS property) can be used on Canvas?

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan yes but it is filled. Im looking for a way to have this shadow with transparent color inside the shape.

Comment: @Dan have you tried using `createRadialGradient`?

Comment: I'm aware it's a css property I don't understand what the op is trying to do. I assumed that you could style the canvas element? I do not have experience with html5 and it was a suggestion not an answer...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An easy trick is to shift the context so the stroke is off-screen, and to shift the shadow back to the right position.

Simple !

```js
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");

var x= 60, y=60, r=40;

var trickShift = { x:10000, y:1000} ;

context.save();
context.beginPath();
context.translate(-trickShift.x, -trickShift.y);
context.lineWidth = 5;
context.shadowColor = 'black';
context.strokeStyle = '#000'; "transparent";
context.shadowBlur = 15;
context.shadowOffsetX = trickShift.x + 100;
context.shadowOffsetY = trickShift.y + 100;
context.arc(x-100, y-100, r, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.stroke();
context.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Upvote, This should be the answer because it better fits the questioner's requirement of shadow with no-stroke.

Comment: @markE ... This creates a completely different type of effect. It's not any more a shadow of an element, rather a **blurred ring**.

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan : i don't get your comment : the blurred shadow of a stroked circle IS a blurred ring.... ?

Comment: @GameAlchemist if you have a circle, it will have a shadow, if you go from opaque to transparent it's shadow will loose intensity (becoming invisible logically if element is transparent) That's how canvas and shadow does it. (i.e:) HTML and CSS are different from nature, the shadow is only applied outside of the element, not underneath it, means you can make an element transparent keeping the shadow (OP's request and my answer) In either case the shadow result of a desirably transparent element is logically not a blurred ring.

Comment: @GameAlchemist read again the last Q's line: `Any Idea to make to have a shadow for an invisible shape ?` So he clearly uses (*arc*) a circle, and your example is clearly not a circle's shadow. Your trick is really valuable in cases... but it was silly to mark it as correct (OP) if you ask me. :\ Someone needs to shape it's *eye for details* mode.

Answer (score 1):

Use `createRadialGradient` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D.createRadialGradient

```
CanvasGradient ctx.createRadialGradient(x0, y0, r0, x1, y1, r1);
```

```js
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var x=80, y=80;
var rg = context.createRadialGradient(x, y, 35, x, y, 45);
rg.addColorStop(0, 'rgba(0,0,0,0.4)');
rg.addColorStop(1, 'rgba(0,0,0,0)');

context.strokeStyle = rg;
context.beginPath();
context.arc(x, y, 40, 2 * Math.PI, false);
context.lineWidth = 10;
context.stroke();
context.restore();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```